# Don't show ReportViewer in DotNetNuke 7

Tags: dotnetnuke, reportviewer

I have a problem with displaying the reportviewer on the page under the platform DNN 7. Element is not visible but is initialized and loaded on the page.
MS VS2103.

Code of reportviewer

```
<tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 25%; height: 400px; display: none;"><div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                    <span id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_DocMap"><div id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl08" style="display:none;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl08$ClientClickedId" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl08_ClientClickedId">
                    </div></span>
                </div></td><td style="display: none; width: 4px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 400px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216);"><div id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl07">
                    <input type="image" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl07$img" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl07_img" title="Show / Hide Document Map" src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterVertCollapse.png" alt="Show / Hide Document Map" align="top" onclick="void(0);" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl07$store" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl07_store"><input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl07$collapse" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl07_collapse" value="false">
                </div></td><td style="height: 400px; vertical-align: top;"><div id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
                    <div id="VisibleReportContentdnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09" style="height:100%;display:none;"></div><div id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ReportArea">
                        <div newcontenttype="Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.None" fornonreportcontentarea="false" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_VisibilityState" style="visibility:none;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl09$VisibilityState$ctl00" value="None">
                        </div><input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ScrollPosition" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ScrollPosition"><span id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget"></span><div id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ReportControl" style="display:none;">
                            <span></span><input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl02"><input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl03"><input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr1387$View$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl04" id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ReportControl_ctl04" value="100">
                        </div><div id="dnn_ctr1387_View_ReportViewer1_ctl09_NonReportContent" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: none;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to track down why DISPLAY:NONE is set in the Style for the viewer. Did you perhaps not bind any data to it?